# Python: compare strptime with strftime

Tags: python, datetime

Good day, I need to write a script that compares a specific time of day, with a specific files "Modified date", in python.

I'm only starting to learn it, and encountered this obstacle.

I have this

```
domt = datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("dom.xlsx")),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

and this

```
now = datetime.now()
targetime = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
targetstr = targetime.strftime("%Y-0%#m-%#d %H:%M:%S")
```

what im trying to achieve is:

```
if targetstr < domt:

.....
```

Which gives me a TypeError that I cant compare str and set.

I understand what I'm doing wrong, which is trying to compare uncomparable variables in which i have target time as a string, and Modified Time as an "Set".

But due my knowledge limitations, and I guess absence of Pythons fundamental rules, I can't resolve this on my own.

I've browsed other threads with Strftime and Strptime issues, but didn't seem to find an answer that relates to my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to compare times, it might be easier to just use the epoch time instead of parsing strings.

```
domt = os.path.getmtime("dom.xlsx") # epoch time of modification

now = datetime.now() # now as datetime
targetime = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
target_epoch = now.timestamp() # epoch of modified datetime object

if domt < target_epoch: # float comparison of epoch timestamps.
    ...
```

If you do want to work with datetimes you need to keep both times as `datetime` objects and then compare them.

```
domt = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("dom.xlsx"))

now = datetime.now() # now as datetime
targetime = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

if domt < targettime: # datetime comparison
    ...
```

Comment: My target file mod.time is 08:03
In epoch solution if I set target time hour to 7

The statement domt < target_epoch:, still goes to if, rather than to else,
same happens if i set it to 9

Comment: The datetime solutions works, setting as solved, thank you so much, but now Im wondering why the epoch one didn't

Comment: There could be a timezone issue. I'm guessing you're not at UTC?

Comment: Might be it, I'm GMT +5

Answer (score 1):

Try simpler:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

targettime = datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), time(16))
timestamp = os.path.getmtime("dom.xlsx")
if targettime < datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp):
    ...
```

Comment: They need to edit the current time to 4pm of the current day.

Comment: Updated the question itself, to avoid confusion. Thank you